# kibana cannot resolve built-in node js modules such as 'fs' when chaging in core source

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, kibana, elastic-stack

I'm trying to add some functionality to kibana core to generate pdf reports from dashbord. 
so in src/ui/public/agg_table.js i have added this line in the controller `var fs = require('fs')` . this gives me the the following error:

```
    ERROR in ./src/ui/public/agg_table/agg_table.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in D:\kibana\src\ui\public\agg_table
 @ ./src/ui/public/agg_table/agg_table.js 43:15-28
```

Unhandled rejection Error: Optimizations failure.

```
ERROR in ./src/ui/public/agg_table/agg_table.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in D:\kibana\src\ui\public\agg_table
 @ ./src/ui/public/agg_table/agg_table.js 43:15-28

at Object.exports.create (D:\kibana\node_modules\boom\lib\index.js:21:17)
at LazyOptimizer.failedStatsToError (D:/kibana/src/optimize/base_optimizer.js:214:17)
at Compiler.<anonymous> (D:/kibana/src/optimize/lazy/lazy_optimizer.js:44:24)
at Compiler.applyPlugins (D:\kibana\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:26:37)
at Watching._done (D:\kibana\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:78:17)
at Watching.<anonymous> (D:\kibana\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:51:17)
at D:\kibana\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:403:12
at Compiler.next (D:\kibana\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:67:11)
at Compiler.<anonymous> (D:\kibana\node_modules\webpack\lib\CachePlugin.js:40:4)
at Compiler.applyPluginsAsync (D:\kibana\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:71:13)
at Compiler.<anonymous> (D:\kibana\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:400:9)
at Compilation.<anonymous> (D:\kibana\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:577:13)
at Compilation.applyPluginsAsync (D:\kibana\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:60:69)
at Compilation.<anonymous> (D:\kibana\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:572:10)
at Compilation.applyPluginsAsync (D:\kibana\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:60:69)
at Compilation.<anonymous> (D:\kibana\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:567:9)
```

so i was wondering why this error occur and if this is the only way to add functionality in kibana core.

Comment: Not that this solves your problem, but I'm curious why you want to fork loba a core rather than build this as a plugin?

Comment: @Paul I thought that is not useful to develop a plugin for little changes

Comment: Seems like that's the main time you would develop a plugin